# "EOF" : syntax error at line 2

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm trying to write a simple vhdl code. When I run this code in quartus 2 there is no problem. However, when I run on modelsim, there is an error at line 2, that is error at "use ieee.std_logic_all.1164;" . I have no clue since I'm new to vhdl. By the way, i'm using Modelsim Starter edition 6.5e

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_all.1164;

entity tb is
end tb;

architecture behaviour of tb is 
component ORG is
port (
a : in std_logic;
b : in std_logic;
c : out std_logic;
 );

 signal ina, inb, outc : std_logic;
 constant period : time := 100ns;
 signal done : boolean := false;


begin
  process
    begin
      ina = '0';
      inb = '0';
      wait for period;


      ina = '1';
      inb = '0'

      wait for period;
      done <= true;
      wait;
  end process;
end behaviour;
```

Comment: Maybe `use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;`

Comment: rene, still failed :(

Comment: Try using the Sigasi editor - it is pretty good at pointing out errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems in your code that will cause syntax errors.

1. As @rene pointed out, the library name is `std_logic_1164` - you have "1164" and "all" reversed (the capitalization of IEEE isn't significant).
2. There should *not* be a semicolon at the end of the `c` port line
3. You should include an `end component;` statement after the port declaration (that is, after the closing parenthesis and semicolon)
4. The equals signs in the process should be `<=`
5. Finally, there should be a space between `100` and `ns`

Comment: 6. Missing semicolon after one of the signal assignments

Comment: @Tomi Junnila thank you very much :) semicolon always the major problem in programmin -.-